# where to map my all dimensions and facts in jasper ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

My databse is oracle 11.1 and Jasper iReport server 5.6

My requirement is to generate level wise reports from all dimensions and facts
then where do i map these dimensions and facts in jasper ireport designer

I have 52 dimensions and 13 facts

Thanks
 Ragav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we Right click on the Report name in the Outline Tab you can see the "Database Query" their you can define the Relationship between fact and dimensions using SQL query.

If any issues let me know.

Comment: What you said absolutely correct and i tried also.But in my database side sql query taking 0.860836 seconds.but in jasper server the same sql query taking too much time(at least 5 minutes).Even I created indexes on joined columns,but the issue is same.

Comment: can you please give me some more information. how many records it has and only that report is taking to long time in the Jasper Server